# Remove item from list angular

Tags: angularjs, splice

I am quite used to the normal MVC server side coding and now I am trying to learn angular. I want to make a user interface where people can add teams to the competition that they signed in to. To remove the teams from the list I am using:

```
angular.module('Xtho.InschrijfController', [])
.controller("InschrCtrl", [
    '$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.model = {};
        $scope.wedstrijden = {};
        $scope.states = {

        };

        $scope.new = {
            ploeg: {}
        };

        $http.get('/inschrijvingen/IndexVM').then(function (data) {
            $scope.model = data;
        });

        $scope.Vploeg = function (id, index) {
            $http.post('/inschrijvingen/PloegVerwijderen', { id: id }).then(function (response) {
                $scope.model.splice(index, 1);
            });
        };

    }
]);
```

and this is within the view:

```
<p>{{ploegen.PloegNaam}} <a href="#" ng-click="Vploeg(ploegen.PloegID, $index)"><span class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></p>
```

The code works! Because the records are deleted from the database, however, they still are in the list shown on the page. The console provides the following error: "n.model.splice is not a function", what is the best way to solve this issue?

Comment: you can wrap the $http.get into a function a recall on the succes of your post.

Comment: `$scope.model` is an object, not an array;  `.splice` is a function on the array prototype.  if `model` truly is a list, then use an array.  don't use an object for lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this.

```
angular.module('Xtho.InschrijfController', [])
.controller("InschrCtrl", [
'$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.model = {};
    $scope.wedstrijden = {};
    $scope.states = {

    };

    $scope.new = {
        ploeg: {}
    };

    $scope.load = function(){
        $http.get('/inschrijvingen/IndexVM').then(function (data) {
            $scope.model = data;
        });
    };
    $scope.load();

    $scope.Vploeg = function (id, index) {
        $http.post('/inschrijvingen/PloegVerwijderen', { id: id 
    }).then(function (response) {
            //$scope.model.splice(index, 1);
            $scope.load();
        });
    };

}
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.model=[]//list
$scope.model={}//javascript object
```

Use $scope.model=[]

Answer (score 0):

In this row you are trying to remove one element of `$scope.model` variable:

```
$scope.model.splice(index, 1);
```

We can use `splice()` only for arrays, but it looks like `$scope.model` is not an array, it was declared as object in your code:

```
$scope.model = {};
```

I don't really know what type the `$scope.model` is, when you're trying to splice an element from it. If it's an object, you better have to remove element by id:

```
$scope.Vploeg = function (id, index) {
  $scope.idForRemove = id;
  $http.post('/inschrijvingen/PloegVerwijderen', { id: id })
    .then(function (response) {
      delete $scope.model[$scope.idForRemove];
    });
  }
}
```